# complex command over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos7

Can someone help me to force this script work please

```
IFLOAD=`ssh root@$REMOTE_HOST 'awk '\''/$IFACE/ {i++; rx[i]=\$2; tx[i]=\$10}; END{print rx[2]-rx[1] " " tx[2]-tx[1]}'\'' <(cat /proc/net/dev; sleep 1; cat /proc/net/dev)'
echo "$IFLOAD"
```

Now it returns

```
0 0
```

But on $2 and $10 columns i have a real data with IFACE rx and tx bytes. Without ssh this script works fine, as i see.

Or maybe you know more easy way to get current measure of interafce load over ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's simplify the `awk` command a little, before worrying about how to pass it through `ssh`.

```
awk_script='
  ifc ~ $1 {
     i++;
     rx[i]=$2;
     tx[i]=$10
    };
  END { 
     print rx[2]-rx[1] " " tx[2] - tx[1]
  }
'
awk -v ifc="$IFACE" "$awk_script" <(cat /proc/dev/net; sleep 1; cat /proc/dev/net)
```

Passing `IFACE` as an `awk` variable lets us enclose the entire `awk` script in one single-quoted string. As long as we double-quote the expansion, it will work as intended.

Now it should be relatively simple to send via `ssh`:

```
IFLOAD=$(ssh root@$REMOTE_HOST "awk -v ifc='$IFACE' '$awk_script' <(cat /proc/dev/net; sleep 1; cat /proc/dev/net)")
```

Note the entire command line is one double-quoted string. That means `$IFACE` and `$awk_script` will be expanded *locally*. That string, though, uses single quotes around the expansions, so that when the entire thing is sent to the remote shell, each value is seen as a single-quoted string, and won't be incorrectly processed by the remote shell.